# numpy array of unexpected dimension

Tags: multidimensional-array, dimension

I'm currently switching from Matlab to Python and I have a problem with understanding numpy arrays.

The following code (copied from Numpy documentation) creates a [2x3] array

`np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)`.

Which behaves as expected.

Now I tried to adapt this to my case and tried

```
myArray = np.array([\
        [-0.000847283,  0.000000000,  0.141182070,   2.750000000],
        [ 0.000876414, -0.025855453,  0.270459334,   2.534537894],
        [-0.000098373,  0.003388169, -0.021976882,   3,509325279],
        [ 0.000077079, -0.004507202,  0.096453685,   2,917172446],
        [-0.000049944,  0.003114201, -0.055974372,   3,933359490],
        [ 0.000042697, -0.003833862,  0.117727186,   2.485846507],
        [-0.000000843,  0.000084733,  0.000169340,   3.661424974],
        [ 0.000000676, -0.000074756,  0.005751451,   3.596300338],
        [-0.000001860,  0.000229543, -0.006420507,   3.758593109],
        [ 0.000006764, -0.000934745,  0.045972458,   2.972698644],
        [ 0.000014803, -0.002140505,  0.106260454,   1.967898711],
        [-0.000025975,  0.004587858, -0.263799480,   8.752330828],
        [ 0.000009098, -0.001725357,  0.114993424,   1.176472749],
        [-0.000010418,  0.002080207, -0.132368251,   6.535975709],
        [ 0.000032572, -0.006947575,  0.499576502,  -8.209401868],
        [-0.000039870,  0.009351884, -0.722882956,  22.352084596],
        [ 0.000046909, -0.011475011,  0.943268640, -22.078624629],
        [-0.000067764,  0.017766572, -1.542265901,  48.344854010],
        [ 0.000144148, -0.039449875,  3.607214322,-106.139552662],
        [-0.000108830,  0.032648910, -3.242170215, 110.757624352]
        ])
```

But not as expected the shape is (20,). I expected the following shape: (20x4).

**Question 1:** Can anyone tell me why? And how do I create the array correctly?

**Question 2:** When I add the datatype `, dtype=np.float`, I get the following
Error:

```
*TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'*
```

but the array isn't intended to be a list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake on my own after trying to `np.vstack` all vectors.
The resulting error said that the size of the arrays with the row index 2, 3, 4 is not 4 as expected.

Replacing a , (comma) with a dot solved the problem.